# Command output and perl output different

Tags: perl, shell

I am having an issue with retrieving the correct information when attempting to run a shell command.  When i run the command on the server i get the correct output, but i do not get the same when it is run through a perl script.

```
$test = `pkginfo | grep TestPackage | awk '{print $2}'`;
print "$test\n";
```

the output when running directly from the shell is:

```
TestPackage
```

While the output from the perl script is:

```
application TestPackage       Description
```

Why would this be different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$2` is being interpolated by perl so that `awk` is only seeing the string `print`.  Try:

```
$test = qx( pkginfo | awk '/TestPackage/{print \$2}' );
print "$test";
```

You can also prevent the interpolation by using single quotes as the delimiter to `qx`:

```
$test = qx' pkginfo | awk \'/TestPackage/{print $2}\' ';
```

Note that `$test` will have a trailing newline unless you `chop` it.

But, invoking `awk` from `perl` is not very perlish.  Although using `awk` feels a lot cleaner, it may be better to do something like:

```
@test = map { m/^\S+\s+(\S+)/; $_ = $1 } grep { /TestPackage/ } qx( pkginfo );
```

Comment: I changed the command to \$2 and everything now works.  Thanks!